# Пользовательские ограничения в авторизации winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть форма авторизации пользователя. Вводимые данные сверяются с базой данных пользователей. Существует несколько условий (логин, пароль, статус, отдел). В зависимости от выбранного отдела и статуса необходимо ограничить кнопки добавления, обновления, удаления. Допустим `button.Enabled = false;`

Этот вариант работает при переходе на следующую форму, отключает кнопку, но если перейти дальше, на другую форму, то отключение не работает. Как указать всем формам пользовательские ограничения?

Код формы авторизации:

```
    namespace newforms
    {
    public partial class login : Form
    {

        public login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        MySqlConnection con = ConDatabase.GetDBConnection();
        Summa summ = new Summa();
        Form1 fm1 = new Form1();
        DSlamSetting setting = new DSlamSetting();
        Dslam dslam = new Dslam();
        stansiya stansiyya = new stansiya();
        request requestt = new request();
        Ochur ochurr = new Ochur();
        port portt = new port();

        private void login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StatusFillCombobox();
            DepartmentFillCombobox();
      //      DostupUslowiyya();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlCommand commandSelect = new MySqlCommand("Select COUNT(*) from login JOIN status ON login.status_id = status.id JOIN department ON login.department_id = department.id where login=@login AND parol=@parol AND status.name = @status AND department.name = @department", con);
            commandSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", LoginTextbox.Text);
            commandSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parol", textBox2.Text);
            commandSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", LoginStatusCombobox.Text);
            commandSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@department", LoginDepartmentCombobox.Text);
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(commandSelect);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);



            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1" && LoginStatusCombobox.Text == "admin")
            {
                this.Hide();

                Form1 fm1 = new Form1();
                fm1.Show();

            }
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1" && LoginStatusCombobox.Text == "employee" && LoginDepartmentCombobox.Text == "vip")
            {

                this.Hide();
                fm1.Show();
                setting.AddDslambutton.Enabled = false;
                setting.DeleteDslambutton.Enabled = false;
                stansiyya.Addbutton.Enabled = false;
                stansiyya.Deletebutton.Enabled = false;
                stansiyya.Updatebutton.Enabled = false;
            }
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1" && LoginStatusCombobox.Text == "employee" && LoginDepartmentCombobox.Text == "GTS")
            {

                this.Hide();
                fm1.Show();
                fm1.ButtonDslamClick.Enabled = false;
                fm1.DslamAdd.Enabled = false;
                fm1.ButtonOchered.Enabled = false;
                fm1.ButtonArzalar.Enabled = false;
           
               
            }
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1" && LoginStatusCombobox.Text == "employee" && LoginDepartmentCombobox.Text == "IT")
            {

                this.Hide();
                fm1.Show();
                fm1.ButtonOchered.Enabled = false;
                fm1.ButtonArzalar.Enabled = false;
                stansiyya.Addbutton.Enabled = false;
                stansiyya.Deletebutton.Enabled = false;
                stansiyya.Updatebutton.Enabled = false;


            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("username or password is not correct");
            }
                
        }

        private void LoginTextbox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (LoginTextbox.Text == "")
            {
                LoginTextbox.Text = "Login";
                LoginTextbox.ForeColor = Color.Silver;
            }
        }

        private void LoginTextbox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (LoginTextbox.Text == "Login")
                LoginTextbox.Text = "";
            LoginTextbox.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
    
        public void StatusFillCombobox()
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter adapterr = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT name FROM status", con);
            DataSet dsett = new DataSet();
            adapterr.Fill(dsett);
            LoginStatusCombobox.ValueMember = "name";
            LoginStatusCombobox.DisplayMember = "name";
            LoginStatusCombobox.DataSource = dsett.Tables[0];
            LoginStatusCombobox.Text = "Status";
        }
        public void DepartmentFillCombobox()
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter adapterr = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT name FROM department", con);
            DataSet dsett = new DataSet();
            adapterr.Fill(dsett);
            LoginDepartmentCombobox.ValueMember = "name";
            LoginDepartmentCombobox.DisplayMember = "name";
            LoginDepartmentCombobox.DataSource = dsett.Tables[0];
            LoginDepartmentCombobox.Text = "Status";
        }
    }      
}
```

есть такая форма где не работает условия

```
namespace newforms
{
public partial class stansiya : Form
{
    MySqlConnection con = ConDatabase.GetDBConnection();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("");
    string query;
    MySqlCommand command;
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    int id;
    public stansiya()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Stansiýa_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        spisok();
        DGVStil.Grid1style(dataGridView1);
        spisokDvG2();

        DVG2Still();
        TimeSet();  // Настроит дататимепикчерс на текущую дату
    //    SelectDslam(); // Выбирает столбец Сатс у сум тейбла
        displayGrid(); // сортирует Дслам что выбирал комбобокс
                       //  probaGrid();
        SelectSatsFromSum();
        SelectDslamId();
        DisplayDatagridview1();
   
    }
```

Comment: Не знаю насколько это правильный способ, но я обычно просто передавал в конструктор формы, которую вызываю, объект класса (не смотрел код, но если у тебя нет класса ```User``` или ```Person```, то передавай просто те переменные, которые нужны будут на другой форме)

Comment: @Pekor , у меня нет таких классов, не могли бы показать в моем примере  как это принимается ?  выше выложу код  формы.

Comment: ```User user = new User() { Login = tbLogin.Text, Password = tbPassword.Text };

   User incommingUser = Authorization_class.Enter(user);

...

MainForm mainForm = new MainForm(incommingUser);```

Comment: Соответственно у тебя будет что-то типо ```Form form = new Form(логин, пароль, статус, отдел);```

Comment: @Pekor , `public stansiya()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        login loggin = new login();
        public stansiya(string login, string parol, string status, string otdel)
        {
            login = loggin.LoginTextbox.Text;
            parol = loggin.ParolTextbox.Text;
            status = loggin.LoginStatusCombobox.Text;
            otdel = loggin.LoginDepartmentCombobox.Text;
            loggin.Dostup();
        }`

Comment: @Pekor, таким образом ?